# How to change font size on one ajax function

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I tried to create a list of questions that pull from database table. I added a code to increase its font size for all questions, but nothing happens.

I added this code: `$("#elem").css("font-size", "20px");`, but it doesn't work at all.

How do I make it work?

Thanks.

Html code: `tbody id="questionList"`

ajax code:

```
function ListQuestions()
{
    $.ajax({
       url:"Function.asp?action=getquestions",
       type:'GET',
       success: function(data){
        $('#questionList').empty();
        $('#questionList').append(data);
        $('.rating').each(function(index,t){
            //console.log(index,$(t).parent().parent().html()); 
            $(t).append(AddControls(index+1));
        });
        $('#questionList').find('.comments').each(function(index,t){
            //console.log(index,$(t).parent().parent().html()); 
            $(t).append(AddTextBox(index+1));
$("#elem").css("font-size", "20px");
        });
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please include you HTML code that goes along with this javascript?

Comment: <tbody id="questionList">

Comment: Why use js to increase font size - why not just add something to your stylesheet?  Also that suspiciously looks like you have multiple `elem` ids.  IDs should be unique (which is probably why your code is not working)

Comment: @JennyTran Can please provide all the HTML (everything referenced in the javascript - `#questionList`, `..rating`, `.comments`, and most importantly `#elem`)?